# Discouraged pragma use GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

Header guards are necessary in nearly all C++ programs, but are a pain when naming conventions are strictly enforced - especially so during refactoring. When using GCC (and many other compilers) we have an alternative in the preprocessor command `#pragma once`. The recommendations I've seen against the use of this command (e.g. lack of support before v3.4) aren't very convincing with regard to my personal projects. I would like to use `#pragma once` if possible.

All that said, this quote from [the GCC website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Pragmas.html) is giving me pause:

> Note that in general we do not recommend the use of pragmas; See [Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes), for further explanation.

Maybe it's just my lower-journeyman-level C++ experience working against me, but I don't see any explanation for that recommendation at the site pointed to by that link. Is anyone able to explain the reasoning behind their recommendation in (semi-)layman's terms?

Comment: Seems like the attributes are a replacement for some of the pragmas (not this one).

Comment: For my personal projects I just use the pragma. If you want to be extra safe you can use both pragma and header guard. The reason for that is pragma might be slightly faster for compilers that support it to process.

Comment: Function attributes have nothing to do with pragma once. They meant other pragmas. You can use it if you think it's pretty and you'll never need to port to a system that doesn't have it, but how likely is that: if the system doesn't have gcc them it probably doesn't drink electricity.

Comment: Even if it is ported, automating the guards where the pragma is found is less error prone and can uniformly use whatever convention turns out to be needed.

Comment: "When naming conventions are strictly enforced" -- could it be your problem isn't so much header guards, but the naming conventions? Perhaps the *solution* would be to e.g. use a UID as guard instead of something derived from the filename, so you don't need to touch it when you change the file name?

Comment: Here's a mildly interesting thing about `#pragma once`: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58770

Comment: And another old (2003) interesting thing, where a GCC dev says that although `#pragma once` was deprecated, it became undeprecated "because it contains a correct implementation at last": https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11569

Comment: And finally, Wikipedia explains some reasons why `#pragma once` isn't trivial to implement, which is why it was once considered for removal from GCC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Caveats

Comment: I *believe* there are slightly different behaviors. One mechanism follows links and does intelligent processing, the other does not (IIRC). Also, Stallman ***despised*** `#pragma once` until the `Pragma` preprocessor macro was added. (He may well still despise it; I don't recall reading anymore about it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general recommendation comes from the fact that not only is there no guarantee that other compilers implement `#pragma once` (or any other pragma), there's no guarantee that other compilers implement `#pragma once` the same way GCC does. Another compiler could legitimately give it an entirely different meaning, or worse, a subtly different one. If you don't care about your code being portable, you can ignore the recommendation.

Personally, I just use normal `#ifndef`/`#define` include guards in my own headers, even for my own personal projects. It's not really all that much typing, and is guaranteed to work everywhere. Naming conflicts with guard macros have never been an issue for me, and I try not to worry about problems I don't have.

Answer (score 4):

I have once done survey of documentation of various C++ compilers and this is the result of the survey:

```
#if defined (_MSC_VER) \
    || (defined (__BORLANDC__) && __BORLANDC__ >= 0x0650) \
    || (defined (__COMO__) && __COMO_VERSION__ >= 400) /* ??? */ \
    || (defined (__DMC__) && __DMC__ >= 0x700) /* ??? */ \
    || (defined (__clang__) && __clang_major__ >= 3) \
    || (defined (__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ >= 4 \
    || (__GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 4)))
# define LOG4CPLUS_HAVE_PRAGMA_ONCE
# pragma once
#endif
```

As you can see, the `#pragma once` is supported by every major compiler out there. This is corroborated by [Wikipedia page of `#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).

So, to answer the original question, the problem with pragmas is that they are very compiler specific. That is way their use in general is discourage for portability reasons. OTOH, this particular pragma is supported across virtually all C++ compilers. Do not feel bad for using it.

Comment: What do you do if you have a compiler that doesn't have `#pragma once` (I know you say all the major ones do, but…).  Don't you have to fall back on the header guards anyway?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, I use both header guards and `#pragma once`.

Comment: The question to ask is that, given it improves clarity and readability, reduces boilerplate, and is supported by pretty much every C++11+ compiler, why is it not in the standard?

I guess the C++20 `module` addresses this.

Comment: Also see : http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0538r0.html